# jQuery Accordion HTML Link Issue

Tags: jquery, html, css, hyperlink

I noticed when i enter a link into the html section of the accordion, the link shows up bold and does not open up. How can i go about fixing this? I thought about creating a class or ID, but after fiddling around, i couldn't get this to work. http://jsfiddle.net/q2Gm9/

Comment: why dont you use jquery toggle function instend of your current function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give target blank then it will work

```
<dl class="accordion">

<dt><a href="">Panel 1</a></dt>
<dd><a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">Google</a></dd>

</dl>​
```

just remove `font-weight:bold` from your class

```
 a {
       display: block;
        color: black;
        font-weight: bold;
      }
```

it should be

```
 a {
       display: block;
        color: black;
        }
```

Comment: Thanks Amit, works perferct! One thing though, how can i get rid of the bold font?

Comment: Thanks @amit The only thing is that by removing the font-weight: bold; the title of the section "panel 1" is no longer bold. How can i fix this so that the link is not bold and the title is?

Comment: add this dt a{ font-weight:bold} into your css

Answer (score 0):

Try to use something like this in script

```
           window.open("www.myaddress.com","_self")
```